# Key is not getting printed to excel from list of dictionaries using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

While trying to export list to dictionaries data to excel using python pandas, only values are getting exported not the keys. Can anyone please help to modify the code so that the keys should also get printed along with values in excel

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

data = [{1:1, 2:2, 3:3}, {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}, {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.transpose()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Pandas-Example.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Do not put pictures of code in your question.... It forces us to re type your code. Copy and paste your code **as text** and put it in the question please.

Comment: `index=False` is not exporting the row index or keys.... Try removing that parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottBoston. It's working fine

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting the index of the dataframe which are your keys by using `index=False`.

Remove index=False, index=True is the default.

```
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
```